# Default arguments in sidekiq perform_async

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I need to access the current_user in sidekiq jobs. One way to do this is pass the current_user in the perform_async, however since it's needed at many places I wanted to add it by default.

So I added a server middleware which would fetch the current_user login and set it in Thread.current, here's my middleware

```
class SidekiqServerMiddleware

  def call(_worker, job, _queue)
    set_current_user(job['args'])
    yield
  end

  private
  def set_current_user(args)
    last_arg = args.last
    return unless last_arg.is_a?(Hash) && last_arg.key?('current_user')
    RequestStore.store[:current_user] = last_arg['current_user']
  end
end
```

I am using `RequestStore` to set Thread.current in thread safe way.

However right now I've to pass `current_user` in the perform_async call. I was searching for a way for sidekiq to do this out of the box but couldn't find any.

One way to achieve this is to create custom module for Sidekiq::Worker

```
module CustomSidekiqWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  before_action set_current_user, only: :perform_async

  def set_current_user
    RequestStore.store[:current_user] = current_user.login
  end
end
```

And then instead of including `Sidekiq::Worker`, include `CustomSidekiqWorker`. Is there a more neat way to do this ? Maybe some ruby meta programming I am missing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I didn't even know that `Sidekiq::Worker` acted like a middleware lol thank you for making me discover it!

Comment: Your last example won't work right?  The thread that enqueues the job is  [most likely] not the thread that performs the job.

Comment: @Anthony Sorry I didn't implement that and test it. I was just sharing what my thoughts are for a solution. I don't know if it'll work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a client/server middleware pair, not just server-side.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware

Comment: Thanks Mike, I tried using that but it is triggered in the background job not in the web server. I need the current_user info which is available while processing the request in the web server, that info is no longer available in background server. I need to do this just before perform_async

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware#sometimes-client-side-middleware-should-be-registered-in-both-places

Comment: The client side middleware runs as part of the perform_async.  It's what you want.